# Why is the below function outputting undefined

Tags: node.js, promise

I am working with google places api to get some data. I cannot figure out why I am getting undefined. I am still new to how promises and asynchronous programs work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code below outputs :

```
Searching Google Places Api for place-id: PLACE_ID_HERE_REPLACED_FOR_QUESTION

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=PLACE_ID_HERE_REPLACED_FOR_QUESTION &fields=formatted_address,geometry,icon,id,name,permanently_closed,place_id,url,vicinity,formatted_phone_number,opening_hours,website,price_level,rating&key= API_KEY_REPLACED_HERE_FOR_QUESTION

TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined
at Promise (/srv/index.js:138:51)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at ... (/srv/index.js:137:3)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
    at /worker/worker.js:783:7
    at /worker/worker.js:766:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)

Function execution took 192 ms, finished with status: 'crash'
```

If I call the url directly, I get a valid result. If I do it through code, I am getting undefined as the result json.

```
function queryPlacesApiByPlaceId(placeId) {
  console.log("Searching Google Places Api for place-id: ".concat(placeId).concat());
  let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid='.concat(placeId).concat('&fields=formatted_address,geometry,icon,id,name,permanently_closed,place_id,url,vicinity,formatted_phone_number,opening_hours,website,price_level,rating').concat('&key=').concat(options.apiKey);
  console.log(url);
  https.get(url, (resp) => {
    let data = '';
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });
    resp.on('end', () => {
      return JSON.parse(data);
    });
  }).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
  });
}

exports.queryPlacesApiByPlaceId = functions.https.onRequest( (req,res) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
  let placeId = req.query['placeId'];
  new Promise(async  (resolve,reject) => {
    resolve(await queryPlacesApiByPlaceId(placeId)['result']);
  }).then( (value) => {
    res.send(value);
  });
});
```

I am expecting the json object to be returned, yet I get an error regarding the promise reject being unresolved. I don't know why my promise would be getting rejected here.

Any tips for how to debug things like this in the future would be greatly appreciated, as I am still trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    resp.on('end', () => {
      return JSON.parse(data);
    });
```

The return statement in this callback only returns inside the callback. It won't return outside the callback to the initial function.
Because you are dealing with async code, you need to either provide a callback to the `queryPlacesApiByPlaceId` function that gets executed when you have the data, or use promises and resolve when you have the data.

```js
function queryPlacesApiByPlaceId(placeId) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log("Searching Google Places Api for place-id: ".concat(placeId).concat());
        let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid='.concat(placeId).concat('&fields=formatted_address,geometry,icon,id,name,permanently_closed,place_id,url,vicinity,formatted_phone_number,opening_hours,website,price_level,rating').concat('&key=').concat(options.apiKey);
        console.log(url);
        https.get(url, (resp) => {
            let data = '';
            resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });
            resp.on('end', () => {
                resolve(JSON.parse(data));
            });
        }).on("error", (err) => {
            console.log("Error: " + err.message);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Makes total sense. Then I can just call .then on the returned promise. I got my function working how I was expecting!